# How to count connections to a host over a given time period? TCP logs?

Tags: linux, perl, security, bash, logging

If I do a

```
 sudo netstat -tup | awk '{print $5}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

I can get a list and count of how many connections I have to each host. But how can I tell how many times I've been connecting to that host ever minute/hour/day? Is there a TCP log somewhere that I can grep through to see how and when I'm connecting to what?

I'm guessing that there is no such log because it would be massive in a short period of time. How would I create such a log with just my desired information? I don't think that using netstat would work for this since it only lists the connections at a give time. without timestamps, I don't have a reliable way to count the connections.

Comment: This is a system configuration question; voting to migrate to serverfault.com.

Comment: I was unaware of that site.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "New connection: "
```

This will log all new outgoing connections, not just TCP. If you only want TCP, add:

```
-p tcp
```

You can grep 'New connection: ' out of syslog.

Comment: Thanks, I also added the -d tag to further narrow it down to the host I was interested in, then I was able to aggregate the connections by minute like so: 

    awk '/New connection:/ {print $1, $2, substr($3,1,5)}' kern.log | uniq -c

Comment: How do you undo the iptables command when you are done? Is it `iptables -D OUTPUT 1`?

Answer (score 1):

IPTables can be used to log connections.

http://linuxdynasty.org/59/how-to-log-in-iptables/